# Visual Studio Extension for Code Alignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style

Is there any **free** extension to perform code alignment, like *[Align Assignments with Productivity Power Tools](http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-align-assignments-in-visual.html?spref=fb)* but to align this code:

```
public int ID;
public string Title;
public string Text;
public decimal Factor;
```

in that way, or something like that?

```
public int      ID;
public string   Title;
public string   Text;
public decimal  Factor;
```

Comment: I can only think of paid ones :\

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 11):

As Pop Catalin said, [Code alignment](http://www.codealignment.com) is what you're after. It's my extension, sorry for not much documentation. It's something that's so much easier to explain with videos, but I'm still to get around to it.

When you align by string it finds the first instance of the string and lines them up. For example if you were to enter '=' then

```
foo = bar;
foobar = foo;
```

would become

```
foo    = bar;
foobar = foo;
```

However, your code doesn't have a common delimiter - except for the space before it. So you can use Align By Space (from the toolbar or ctrl + =, ctrl + space, but you'll have to remove what's already assigned to ctrl + =). Align By Space uses your caret location (you can still select the row you want to align, or let the extension figure it out) and aligns by the first space on each line after your caret location.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Code Alignment for Visual Studio just became one of my favorite plugins. I can now align "//" comments extremely quickly. My C++ coworkers are going to love this too. Thanks!

Comment: Note that align by space doesn't seem work very well if you select the stuff you want to align. This confused me for a long time. Just position the caret and click align by space.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Code alignment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) ;)

P.S. I haven't tried it myself but it looks like it does what you need, so if it's good you can leave a comment here, so more people will know.

Comment: Just installed it, but can't make it work, it is asking my `Enter string to align` what should I type? the documentation is so poor :(