# Visual C++ keeps destroying my code formatting alignment

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, code-formatting, autoformatting

I'm working on an open source project that uses horizontal alignment in source code. The code is written in C++, and I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Visual Studio tries to be smart concerning spacing, but ends up destroying my manual alignment.

A typical piece of code looks like this:

```
bool  →   →   → GetFieldWithType  →   → ( int idx, cc8* name, int type );
bool  →   →   → GetFieldWithType  →   → ( int idx, int key, int type );
static cc8*   → GetLuaTypeName    →   → ( int type );
void* →   →   → GetPtrUserData    →   → ( int idx );
```

Now, if I add another line just like this, as soon as I type the opening parenthesis (after two tabs), Visual Studio removes the two tabs I just entered and replaces them with a single space. I try to be patient and hit Ctrl+Z to undo the automatic formatting. But as soon as I type the semicolon, it kills the tabs all over again.

I found an option in *Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Spacing > Spacing for function parentheses* that toggles whether to insert a space before the opening parenthesis of an argument list. If I deactivate this option, VS still insists on removing the tabs before the opening parenthesis, it just doesn't add a space. **How do I get rid of this behavior?**

To be clear: I'm fine with VS automatically *inserting* spaces (according to what I configured). I don't want to deactivate automatic formatting altogether. I just don't want it to remove the spacing I just manually entered.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use tabs for alignment if you want your code to still look good when displayed in someone else's text editor / IDE, because they may use a different tab length than you do. For indentation, tabs _might_ be okay if it's done consistently (which is usually difficult to enforce in practice in a team with many people).

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++`.

Under `Tabs` you can change "Insert spaces" to "Keep tabs". If you don't want VS mucking up your indentation at all, you can also turn off indenting here.

Under `Formatting > Spacing` you can uncheck (almost) all the "Remove space..." options.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried all these options before. "Keep tabs" is already active, the relevant "Remove spaces..." options are disabled. The "Indenting" option under Tabs only controls the left-indentation of the entire line, but not within a line. No luck here!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565367/visual-studio-extension-for-code-alignment links to an extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd - perhaps that will help?